# I don't see SVG on my website while using NEXTjs

Tags: svg, next.js

### i have problem with importing SVG to my NextJS website.

I've tried using <Image /> tag, <img /> tag too and <svg> tag also.
Webstorm sees the image, but browser doesn't.

code:

```
import Logo from "../public/file.svg"

const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <nav>
                <div>
                    <Image src={Logo} alt="logo" height={50} width={50}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this. The problem was gone when I replaced the imported `.svg` file and placed the URL directly in the `Image`. like this:

```
const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    //...
    <Image src="/file.svg" alt="logo" height="50px" width="50px"/>
  );
}
```

Notice that with this method, you start your URL with a `/` from public folder and should not include `../public` itslef.

Comment: Thanks, it loads the file.svg now in devtools (inspect elements), but it's still not visible. When i drag it to new tab, i see it. So maybe there's problem in some property of NextJS's <Image /> ?

Comment: Or may be there is a problem with your browser. Did you try with different browsers?